# Can we show differentiability uniformly wrt a parameter here?

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity, frechet-derivative

Let $E_i$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space, $\Omega\subseteq E_1$ be open, $(M,d)$ be a compact metric space and $f:\Omega\times M\to E_2$ be continuous.

> Assume $f(\;\cdot\;,y)$ is Fréchet differentiable for all $y\in M$ and ${\rm D}_1f:\Omega\times M\to\mathfrak L(E_1,E_2)$ is continuous. Are we able to conclude that the differentiability is uniformly with respect to the second argument, i.e. $$\frac1{\left\|h\right\|_{E_1}}\sup_{y\in M}\left\|f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)-{\rm D}_1f(x,y)h\right\|_{E_2}\xrightarrow{h\to0}0\tag1$$ for all $x\in\Omega$.

If necessary, assume that $\Omega$ is relatively compact such that we can infer that $f$ and ${\rm D}_1f$ are uniformly continuous.

Let $\varepsilon>0$. By the plain definition of Fréchet differentiable of $f(\;\cdot\;,y)$ for all $y\in M$, we only obtain that there is a $(\delta_y)_{y\in M}\subseteq(0,\infty)$ with $$\frac{\left\|f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)-{\rm D}_1f(x,y)h\right\|_{E_2}}{\left\|h\right\|_{E_1}}<\varepsilon\tag2$$ for all $h\in B_{\delta_y}(0)$ and $y\in M$.

### Example

Assume, for example, that $\Omega=[0,\tau]$ for some $\tau>0$, that $f(\;\cdot\;,x)$ is differentiable for all $x\in M$ and that $\partial_1f$ is (jointly) continuous. Then (since $M$ is compact) $\partial_1f$ is uniformly continuous and hence, given $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ with $$\left\|\partial_1f(r,x)-\partial_1f(s,y)\right\|_{E_2}<\varepsilon\tag3$$ for all $r,s\in[0,\tau]$ and $x,y\in M$ with $\max(|r-s|,\left\|x-y\right\|_E)<\delta$. Thus, $$\left\|\frac{f(t,x)-f(s,x)}{t-s}-\partial_1f(s,x)\right\|_{E_2}\le\frac1{t-s}\int_s^t\left\|\partial_1f(r,x)-\partial_1f(s,y)\right\|_{E_2}{\rm d}r<\varepsilon\tag4$$ for all $s,t\in[0,\tau]$ with $|s-t|<\delta$ and $x\in M$.

> Can we generalize this result?

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: @BehnamEsmayli The question is whether we can show $(1)$.

Comment: Have you thought about showing that $ y \to \delta(y)$ is lower semicontinuous? Because then by compactness  $\delta = \min_y \delta(y)$ would be positive.

Comment: @BehnamEsmayli I didn't thought about that. But do you expect the semicontinuity hold for an arbitrary or a specific choice of the $\delta_y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\frac{1}{\|h\|_E}(f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)-D_1f(x,y)h) = \int_0^1{\left(D_1f(x+th,y)-D_1f(x,y)\right)\frac{h}{\|h\|_E}}$.

Thus, the conclusion follows as soon as $D_1f(x',y)$ converges (in norm) uniformly in $y$, as $x' \rightarrow x$, to $D_1f(x,y)$ (*).

Let $g=D_1f: \Omega \times M \rightarrow E_3$, which is continuous. We'll show that (*) follows from the continuity of $g$.

Indeed, if (*) doesn't hold, as $M$ is compact, we can take sequences $x_n,y_n$ converging to $x,y$ respectively, such that for some $\epsilon>0$, $\|g(x_n,y_n)-g(x,y_n)\| > \epsilon$. But as $g$ is continuous, $g(x_n,y_n) \rightarrow g(x,y)$ and $g(x,y_n) \rightarrow g(x,y)$, a contradiction.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer. I think even the direct proof which I gave in the question for the special case could be generalized or do you think that won't work?

Comment: It’s easily generalizable to the finite dimensional case. But what’s happening in infinite dimension is subtler as you lose local compactness (and hence local on $\Omega$ uniform continuity). What saves us is that the right hypothesis is slightly weaker than uniform continuity.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. The uniformity is not meant to hold over $x\in\Omega$ as well. So, for a fixed $x\in\Omega$, we can consider a relatively compact open neighborhood $N$ of $x$ and consider the restriction of $f$ and ${\rm D}_1f$ on $N\times M$. Or what did you mean?

Comment: In infinite dimension, compacts have empty interior, so you can’t do that.